# Integrity of a hashmap sent over network

Tags: security, stream, hashmap, equals, digest

My servlet encrypts and sends a HashMap and its MD5 hash. 
The client then receives them, and compares the MD5 with one it works out from the HashMap.

This works sometimes but not others, eg, if the HashMap is:

```
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    result.put("error", 0);
    result.put("coun", 0);
```

That works

However, if it's:

```
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    result.put("error", 0);
    result.put("count", 0);
```

It doesn't work - the two MD5 hashes are different. (only difference being the key 'count' instead of 'coun')

The program sends similar HashMaps, all containing keys/values that are only Strings or Integers, and this is the first time i've seen something wierd like this.

Details of how the HashMap/MD5 is actually sent -

Server does:

```
    //Work out MD5 of the HashMap result (convert it to bytes with objectOutputStream, and MD5 the bytes)
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
    out.writeObject(result);
    out.close();
    byte[] md5 = messageDigest.digest(bos.toByteArray();

    //Encrypt the httpURLConnection response stream, and send the HashMap result and the md5 over the stream
    Cipher symmetricCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    symmetricCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, symmetricKey);
    CipherOutputStream cipherOutput = new CipherOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), symmetricCipher);
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(cipherOutput);
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
    objectOutput.writeObject(result);
    objectOutput.writeObject(md5);
    objectOutput.flush();
```

The client does:

```
    //Decrypt the httpURLConnection response stream
    Cipher symmetricCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
    symmetricCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, symmetricKey);
    CipherInputStream cipherInput = new CipherInputStream(httpInput, symmetricCipher);
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(cipherInput);           

    //read HashMap and MD5
    ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    HashMap<String, Object> result = (HashMap<String, Object>) objectInput.readObject();
    byte[] hash1 = (byte[]) objectInput.readObject();

    //workout hash of the Hashmap received.
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
    out.writeObject(result);
    out.close();
    byte[] hash2 = messageDigest.digest(bos.toByteArray();

    // Compare two hashes
    if (!Arrays.equals(hash1, hash2)) {
        System.out.println("Result received does not match hash, stopping list operation");
        return;
    }
```

decrypts using the same type of inputStreams, works out the md5 of the hashmap in the same way, and then compares using:

```
    if (!Arrays.equals(hash1, hash2)) {
            System.out.println("Result received does not match hash, stopping get operation");
            return;
    }
```

I don't understand why this has worked for sending all the HashMaps i've tried, but doesn't work now with this count key.
I've tested comparing the individual key/value pairs inside the HashMap on the client and servlet, and they are the same, but when comparing the two MD5's of the whole HashMap they don't match.

Also, I'm not sure i'm using the buffered stream at the correct part of the stream chain?

Comment: You say, "the two MD5 hashes are different", which two MD5 hashes are you talking about here, *specifically*?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that two copies of Java will produce exactly the same bytes as a serialization of an object -- only that they will produce a semantically equivalent object.

You could make something like this work by running the digests on the keys and values, but you'd need to decide how to hash the `Object` values.

If you can render to XML, and canonicalize that, then you could go from there.

You could look in to the various web service standards for security instead of rolling your own.

Suggestion: copy the hash map into a TreeMap, which has an order, and try the same trick with that.

Comment: thx, just assumed there was a guarantee because its been working for lots of different hashmaps until now fine - thought it was ok because they only contained integers and strings...any idea of why this specific hashmap is the one that it stops working for? Have to roll my own, its for an assignment

Comment: No guarantee, is it is walking the map in an undefined order.

Comment: ok will try treemap, else i'll just MD5 the stuff in the hashmap rather than the serialized bytes...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be just send JSON with key value pairs from one JVM and on the receiver side, you can deserialize and construct another HashMap